# How to remove header attribute from Axis2 SOAP response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am trying to remove the header attributes from a SOAP response.

I have searched and ran across the idea that setting the `mustUnderstand` option too false will remove the header attribute element, but not the header tag.

How do I remove the header tag from an Axis2 SOAP response? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can write `SoapHandler` that intercepts all your soap requests. Inside `SoapHandler` you have access to `SoapMessageContext` than obtain `SoapMessage.getEnvelope().getHeader()` and play with header in all ways (remove/add header elements). This approach good because you introduce new layer in your api and can preprocess inbound and outbound messages without impact on your main code.
Maybe following link will help you http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-soap-message-handlers

Comment: i do not need header part (Need to delete header tag). Is it possible ?

Comment: soap message is xml document. Header is just node in xml. Can you delete node from xml?

Comment: We can delete node in xml. but with the server response i don't know how the header tag could be deleted. i could not create any header nodes. but, when soap request happens it takes automatically because each http response has header information i think so...

Comment: don't confuse http header and soap header